# UILabel with multiple line doesnt show all the lines when there is a superscript of baselineOffset 5

Tags: uitableview, uilabel, swift4

I have a UILabel within a tableviewcell. I have given leading, trailing top and bottom constraints to the label. I have set tableview row height as `UITableview.automaticDimension` and estimated row height as 100.

Then added the following code in tableviewcell

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

Also my label is prefixed with a superscript of numbers which has `baselineOffset` 5.The superscript has font size 6 and the rest of the text has font size 11. So for this I am adding `attributedText` to my label.

When I load the tableview, all the lines are not coming through, the text cuts off in the middle.

I tried many solutions from google but no luck. Can anyone please share your thoughts, on how i can fix this issue.

Comment: “Also my label is prefixed with a superscript of numbers“ So is that relevant? If you don’t do that, does the issue go away?

Comment: Also does the cell contain anything else?

Comment: @matt: I just added that point thinking whether it has anything to do with the label adjustments. Label contains a superscript and then it has 3,4 lines text.

Comment: Ok but you are not answering my questions and you are not giving enough info to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Dont know why there is a downvote on this question. This is a valid scenario only I believe.

Comment: Can you post a project that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: There is an update on this .. The problem comes when I am using attributed text in the label. If it is plain it works. So for adding the superscript, I added attributedText and this happens.Updated the question

Comment: But that still isn’t enough info for me to reproduce. If you can’t post an example or give better instructions I can’t help.

Comment: I will update the project soon @Matt... thanks for the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the above one worked by using 2 UILabels. Whenever I was using a superscript at the beginning it was getting ended up with one line less than the original content.So I used a label for the superscript and another label for the rest of the content.Both are having the same Leading constraint and prefixing the second label with needed spaces as given below. Also adjusted the first label by giving needed top space constraint to the container.

> secondLabel.text = (row > 8 ? "  " : " ") + secondLabelContent

Note: When I give the superscript at the end of the label content it works fine with attributedText in single label.